# WooCommerce - How to remove blank space

Tags: html, css, wordpress, text, woocommerce

I just learned how to remove the **Shop** text on WooCommerce:

```
.page-title {
display: none !important;
}
```

but I see a empty space where the text was. How would I remove this empty space and move the content below up by using CSS?

Comment: Please share us html/php code too.

Comment: Share your code in running environment like fiddle..

Comment: you learned it wrong at first place... hiding a h1 text in your website is never a good idea....
Be prepared for negative SEO ranking for this.....

You should have re evaluated your template files for this.... Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'modify_woocommerce_page_title' );

function modify_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title ) {
    if( $page_title == 'Shop' ) {
           return '';
    }
}
```

Alternatively this will probably work better to remove the white space, place the code in your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', false );
```